# Determine if app exists in iOS, Android, and Windows Phone before opening URL?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, windows-phone-8, cordova

We're developing a phoneGap (Appery.io) app where the user can open Facebook links. Ideally, if the person has Facebook App installed, we'd like to open the "fb://" url instead of the "https://" url. What would be the cross-platform (iOS / Android / Windows / BlackBerry) function to determine if either: (1) "fb://" works or (2) the Facebook app is installed to determine the URL structure for that device?

Ideally it work work like this: openFacebookURL('url');

where openFacebookURL either opens in the Facebook App or, if the App doesn't exist, in "ChildBrowser".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed way to check this across all platforms.

Instead I'd present both options and remember which one they chose and make that the default for future use.

Comment: There must be a way in JavaScript to check each platform (Android, iOS, Windows)...

Comment: @AriTeman Why "must" there be a way? There definitely isn't in Windows. As URI schemas can be supported by multiple apps you'll also need to consider what happens if two apps supported the fb schema.